# Программное создание градиентного изображение

Tags: изображения, ios

Здравствуйте!

Цель - установить градиентную заливку для кнопки в состоянии `Highlighted` и `Normal` БЕЗ использования ресурсов `png`.

Первое решение - замещение стандартного `drawRect` и ручная отрисовка в зависимости от состояния. Все работает, но анимация при нажатии иногда происходит очень быстро и поэтому пришлось ставить временную задержку в 0.1 сек. между отрисовкой кнопки в состоянии `Highlighted` при нажатии и отрисовкой в состоянии `Normal` при отжатии.

Второе решение - программно создать два изображения на основе градиентов и задать их в методе `setBackgroundImage:forState` для каждого из состояний.

Вопрос - как программно создать градиентное изображение? Нашел ф-ию `CGImageCreate`, но не могу понять, как при ее использовании создать изображение на основе градиента. Подскажите, пожалуйста, если кто-то пробовал так делать.

Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: Точно не вспомню, но если надо будет, то вспомнить смогу, но мой подход был немного другой: я игрался со слоями    `CALayer`    через библиотеку    `QuartzCore`.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно создать картинку с градиентом то 1 вариант, создаем ImageContext, рисуем квадрат с грдиентом и получаем UIImage, хотя для кнопок правильнее будет использовать drawRect

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(100,100));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

NSArray* gradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
    (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, 
    (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor, nil];
CGFloat gradientLocations[] = {0, 1};
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (CFArrayRef)gradientColors,     gradientLocations);

UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
CGContextSaveGState(context);
[rectanglePath addClip];
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(50, -0), CGPointMake(50, 100), 0);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGGradientRelease(gradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: .

    UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext // wtf???
    ObjectiveCWithALotOfLongAndFuckingStupidVariableNames // ...

Comment: @AlexWindHope  вы так оригинальны. 
То ли дело [SQL](http://govnokod.ru/221).

Comment: @VioLet покажите мне там слово длиной 41 символ, к тому-же это битрикс, приводить примеры кода оттуда ничего не доказывают.

Или вы хотите сказать что у ObjC отличное именование? Если да, то это уже клиника

Comment: @AlexWindHope, как-то странно экстраполировать частные случаи именований на весь язык, вы не находите?   
Поэтому давайте рассматривать данный конкретный случай: вот описание данной функции из оф. документации   
> A image object containing the contents of the current bitmap graphics context.  
  
Придумайте, пожалуйста, более лаконичное название. Я не ёрничаю, и мне тоже не всегда нравятся длинные именования, но альтернатив не вижу.  
*P.S. под «альтернативой» я имел в виду такое название, при котром читаемость кода не уменьшается.*

Comment: @Violet в "нормальных" языках это имело-бы примерно такой вид, чувствуете разницу?

    UIGraphics.currentImageContext.getImage();

Comment: @AlexWindHope, не чувствую, увы.   
Ну и потом, данная функция написана не на Objective-C, а на Си.

Comment: @VioLet, ну, если вы не чувствуете разницы, тогда, конечно, спорить неочем, возможно, со временем и привыкаешь и разницы не видно, не знаю.

"данная функция написана не на Objective-C, а на Си." ObjC - валидный C код, соответственно, технически, в какой-то степени, любой С код можно считать ObjC кодом, да и речь не оь этом.

В общем-то я ничего не имею против, мне просто жалко ОП своего мозга :)

Comment: -(void)AlexWindHopeWillTerminate {
        return YES;
    }

Comment: @Awesome, как-то это скорее в пользу @AlexWindHope :)

Comment: главное все просто и понятно.
а не нравится пиши так:
Load proc
    mov     cx,hth
Aloop:
    push    cx
    mov     di,cx
    shl     cx,6
    shl     di,8
    add     di,cx
    mov     ah,3fh
    mov     cx,wth
    mov     dx,offset slne
    int     21h
    cld
    mov     cx,wth
    mov     si,offset slne
    rep     movsb
    pop     cx
    loop    Aloop
    ret
    Load endp